# Memory fault(coredump) in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have a problem with my script, it works fine when I loaded a file with fewer records but displays **Memory fault(coredump)** with file with many records. I suspected this grep code below:

```
 grep "$(awk '{anum=substr($1,3,13); sub(/^0+/, "", anum); print anum}' file1.txt)" file2.txt > output.txt
```

My resolution is to do it with **awk** alone but since I'm new to it, I'm seeking for your help.

This is the sample data: (Please note that I'm using thousands of records for both files)

file1.txt

```
 5000000000009258378
 5000000000008523654
```

file2.txt

```
 9258378, 9258380
 8665231, 8665231
 8523654, 8523658
```

output.txt

```
 9258378, 9258380
 8523654, 8523658
```

Comment: Make sure your files exist

Comment: You suspect that grep code? Stick an `echo` before and after that line to confirm it!

Comment: @John3136 I now tried to execute the grep code alone and says Memory fault(coredump). Note: I used 2 files with 2,155 records (file1) and 5904 rec (file2)

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the output of this :

```
awk '{anum=substr($1,3,13); sub(/^0+/, "", anum); print anum}' file1.txt
```

converting it to a string in the shell, and then passing that string as an argument to grep.

If the output is large, the shell or grep might choke on it.

In any case, I don't think that is what you mean to do--

If the output of the awk script is multiple lines, you probably want to handle that in a loop in the shell, and run grep separately for each line.